# Python Twisted or Concurrence Programming for Learning Sockets/Networking

Tags: python

Well this is my last ditch effort of finding help/guidance.  We've only just started learning Python at university and i really want to get a jump on everyone else and i've really been focusing on networking with Python.  I've had a look at the twisted framework and it's massive ! even the krondo.com site is.

I've seen Concurrence for python on LinuxQuestions a couple of times, which seems easier (however it looks like Concurrence has been dis-continued?), and was wondering if im better off knuckling down and really getting into twisted or maybe trying something else.... Its not that im afraid of hard work, but i dont want to go down a path that when im finished, i find out that know one use's it out in the real world, or knows of it.

Im sorry its not a technical question, but this is really the only place where i know i can get proper guidance.  If you think putting my head down and learning twisted will be worth my while, then ill do that.  Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: There's more wisdom in doing it wrong and learning why, then in doing it unknowingly right. ;-) It depends on what you want - besides being on top?

Comment: I would recommend that you learn the *basics* first. There are several great resources for learning about sockets, which are the basics of the internet. I would visit [this link](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Python/Sockets-in-Python/) which gives you a basic overview of sockets. Then, I would ask questions and understand them fully. Once you can cognate the lower level stuff, I would *then* go to `Twisted` which I have heard is really powerful.

Comment: Thanks for that link xxmbabanexx, i've already done the low level stuff and have no problems with server/clients, i guess ill just have a cup of cement and knuckle down and learn twisted.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I would take a step back on frameworks and work with the Python standard library on a more basic level. The python docs are a very good and authoritative source of information on Python. If you're looking into networking, here's a path I'd recommend looking over:

- [Sockets](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/socket.html)

  - Learn how to work with basic socket connections, making clients, and making servers.
- [SSL](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ssl.html)

  - A lot of web services use this to communicate data securely for APIs. It may be difficult to wrap your head around, but it's a highly valuable piece of knowledge to have.
- [Select](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/select.html)

  - One way of handling multiple clients connecting to a service. This gets into the concurrency realm which is a fairly sought after skill.
- [Threads](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html)

  - Another way of handling multiple connections, networking tasks.
- [Protocols](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/internet.html)

  - Now that you've wrapped your head around basic networking, it's time to get into protocols. These are sending specifically formatted data over the network to a server that can handle such data. Yes, I'd recommend going through all the different protocols.
- [Data Parsing](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/netdata.html)

  - Data that is sent and received during different protocol communication can be encoded in various ways to make it easier to deal with data.
- [Pack and Unpack](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html)

  - Sometimes network communication isn't done with a standard format. These functions are helpful in dealing with binary protocols if there's no library available.
- [Pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)

  - This is some advanced stuff and python specific. You can use it to send python objects over the network. Just be careful to do this on **trusted networks only** for security purposes.

With that in mind these are general recommendations. Check the docs out, write some code, and ask questions if you get stuck.