# Scraping Price Data from Product Catalog on a Website

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am familiar with urllib as I have used it in class to parse data from Google's currency converter, but now I want to create a web scraper that takes prices from this site nextworth.com.

As you can see it isn't as easy as grabbing data from one page (like you would for gold prices or whatnot), but there are many products and many questions needed to answer to show the final price. This is how it would work:

`1.` Go to the site (http://www.nextworth.com)

`2.` Click on a product category (ex. iPhones) http://nextworth.com/search/1/cat/iphones/

`3.` Click on the actual product (ex. iPhone 4 16GB ATT) http://nextworth.com/product/293814/cat/iphones/apple_iphone_4_16gb_(black)_-_at&t/

Then what you have is a series of questions in order to give you an instantaneous quote. Thus, next steps would be

`4.` Powers on fully functional - Yes

`5.` Cracked Display - No

And finally, the price is displayed. This is what I want to scrape and store. Right now I am working on only getting the prices for perfect condition items because its easier, but keep in mind that I also would want the prices if step 4 was No and step 5 No, or step 4 - Yes and step 5 - Yes, etc.

So I guess my question is, what would the psuedocode (logical steps) behind writing code for this program be like? Is it even feasible to do this or will it take forever and tons of lines of code? Should I start by creating several functions that are for each category, and then within them I have each product (I feel like that would take forever). Or should I use classes for each category and embedded functions?

EDIT: I guess I should ask if Python would even be a good language to do it in, hopefully it is feasible to do it in Python as I only know that and C++ so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For website scraping in general, there's a nice [webscraping module](http://docs.webscraping.com/index.html) that you can use. The nice thing is that it can utilize the QtWebkit module so you can even handle javascript heavy sites.

With that in mind though I have to warn you on this sort of thing.

What you're doing is an automated process that given your requirement appears as though it's going to hit lots of pages. If you don't have permission from the website that you're scrapping from, you could get blocked from their servers for using up resources that could be pulling in live human customers that they care about.

In these sort of cases you want to be dealing with an API of some sort. See if the site has an API, because those are a **lot** more friendly towards automated processes, as long as you abide by their API rules.

Comment: Thank you for the warning, unfortunately I do not think they have a public API. Perhaps it is not as feasible of a task as I thought.

Comment: @Goose I would just contact them and see. If you're really just doing it to learn, explain it. They could also have an API in the works, or maybe they use another API themselves. The worst that can happen is they turn down your request. If you really want to get into some higher level practical stuff, look into the [AWS API python bindings](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforpython/). That's a **highly** marketable and useful skill.

Comment: @Goose Hmm, I think you should take a look then at Python and networking at a lower level. I put [together a guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261052/python-twisted-or-concurrence-programming-for-learning-sockets-networking/15261500#15261500) that has recommended parts to look at in the Python documentation. Once you've got your head wrapped around that I'd look at tackling the AWS stuff again.

Answer (score 1):

Webscraping libraries require that you set up some form of libraries as well as integrated development environment in your case, you are considering picking up python for this.

We have created a webscraping as a service platform that allows you to [automate webscraping in a few click](https://krake.io). While we are still in the process of creating a chrome browser extension the first version of which we will release end of this week. You just have to write a few lines of JSON before you can use us to do your web scraping for you.